# sharing files from app and pc

Tags: windows-phone-8

I created an app which records audio and adds some effect to it (Voice Instagram!).

Currently, I save an mp3 versions of these files in Local Storage folder.
For my debug purposes I need to access this files from my PC. And this is the problem!

WP8 does not allow me to write in any public folder (Documents, Music, ...) and I cannot access internal app files from my PC.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using SkyDrive and uploading files there.